# How to do something with JavaScript when html's class name changes?

Tags: javascript

I am using Swiper.js for creating slider, it works well, slider moves infinitely, as slide appears class name is added called "swiper-slide-active".

[image]

I want to do something with JavaScript when slide is active(class name is "swiper-slide-active"), for example console.log("hello")

here is my solution, but it logs once not infinitely:

```js
const swiperSlide = document.querySelectorAll(".swiper-slide");
const activeSlide = document.querySelector(".swiper-slide-active");

swiperSlide.forEach(swiper => {
  if(swiper.classList.value === "swiper-slide swiper-slide-active"){
    console.log("hello");
  }
});
```

How can I do it infinitely as slide becomes active? so how can I console.log "Hello" simultaneously as slide becomes active? thanks in advance

Comment: Use their API? https://swiperjs.com/swiper-api#events

Answer (score -1):

You could use  [MutationObserver](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/MutationObserver) for this and listen for changes in attributes on element.

So if `mutation.type === 'attributes'` and `mutation.target.classList.contains('swiper-slide-active')` do something.

**Example:**

```js
const swiperSlide = document.querySelectorAll(".swiper-slide")[0];


const targetNode = swiperSlide
const config = {
  attributes: true,
  childList: false,
  subtree: false
};
const callback = function(mutationsList, observer) {
  for (const mutation of mutationsList) {
    if (mutation.type === 'attributes') {
      if (mutation.target.classList.contains('swiper-slide-active')) {
        console.log(".swiper-slide added")
      } else {
        console.log(".swiper-slide removed")
      }
      console.log('The ' + mutation.attributeName + ' attribute was modified.');
    }
  }
};
const observer = new MutationObserver(callback);
observer.observe(targetNode, config)



setInterval(function() {
  swiperSlide.classList.toggle('swiper-slide-active');
}, 2000);
```

```css
.swiper-slide {
  font-size: 50px;
  color: green
}

.swiper-slide-active {
  background-color: blue
}
```

```html
<div class="swiper-slide">slide</div>
```